# When would a JVM store member variable references on the stack?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm reading [section 12.6.1 of Java SE specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1) and it said:

> Optimizing transformations of a program can be designed that reduce the number of objects that are reachable to be less than those which would naively be considered reachable. For example, a Java compiler or code generator may choose to set a variable or parameter that will no longer be used to null to cause the storage for such an object to be potentially reclaimable sooner.
>
> Another example of this occurs if the values in an object's fields are stored in registers. The program may then access the registers instead of the object, and never access the object again. This would imply that the object is garbage. Note that this sort of optimization is only allowed if references are on the stack, not stored in the heap.

The relevant code is:

```
class Foo {
    private final Object finalizerGuardian = new Object() {
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            /* finalize outer Foo object */
        }
    }
}
```

My question is what kind of JVM would ever store finalizerGuardian in the stack not the heap and why?

Comment: I guess, you're misreading it (it's pretty unreadable to me). An optimizing JVM may want to disassemble `Foo` and all it's parts and store it all in registers, but *"This sort of transformation is therefore not legal: the inner class object should be reachable for as long as the outer class object is reachable"*.

Comment: @maaartinus actually, the specification does not prohibit disassembling the `Foo` instance (and in turn the entire object graph). What it does not allow, is collecting the inner object instance when `Foo` is still on the heap. Or simpler said, it does not allow collecting the inner object earlier than the outer, whereas collecting both together is no problem (it would be a performance disaster if every object had to get collected individually). And in that case, it's important to keep in mind that there is no guaranteed order for the `finalize` invocations anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The code example is for illustrating the last sentence of your cited text, “*Note that this sort of optimization is only allowed if references are on the stack, not stored in the heap*” and it is a bit odd that you ripped it off the explaining text:

> *For example, consider the* Finalizer Guardian *pattern:*
>
> ```
>  class Foo {
>      private final Object finalizerGuardian = new Object() {
>          protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
>              /* finalize outer Foo object */
>          }
>      }
>  }
> ```
>
> *The finalizer guardian forces `super.finalize` to be called if a subclass overrides `finalize` and does not explicitly call `super.finalize`.*
>
> *If these optimizations are allowed for references that are stored on the heap, then a Java compiler can detect that the `finalizerGuardian` field is never read, null it out, collect the object immediately, and call the finalizer early. This runs counter to the intent: the programmer probably wanted to call the Foo finalizer when the Foo instance became unreachable. This sort of transformation is therefore not legal: the inner class object should be reachable for as long as the outer class object is reachable.*

So the code example illustrates a restriction. The “optimizing transformations” mentioned by the specification includes Object Scalarization applied after Escape Analysis has proven that an object is purely local, in other words, the code under optimization spans the entire lifetime of the object.

But it doesn’t need such local objects. As the specification already mentioned, optimized code may keep an object’s fields in CPU registers without the need to re-read them, thus, does not need to keep the object reference anymore. Likewise, a reference variable still in scope may be unused. If that reference was the only reference to an object, removing it from the optimized code allows earlier garbage collection.

Both scenarios would still allow a `Foo` instance to get eliminated or collected earlier. This in turn would allow the earlier collection of the object (not anymore) referenced by `finalizerGuardian`. But that doesn’t counteract the intention of this restriction. The specification restricts the optimization to not allow the inner object to get collected earlier than the outer object, but there is no problem in collecting both together, including earlier than naively expected.

Generally, arbitrarily large object graphs may get collected in a single garbage collection cycle, perhaps earlier than naively expected, or even get optimized away completely.

Answer (score 1):

a classic example for such kind of optimization (escape analysis) is a calculation with `Point` class:

```java
class Point {
    double x;
    double y;

    public Point(final double x, final double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    double length() {
        return Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    static double calc() {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            // this allocation will be optimized 
            Point point = new Point(i, i);
            result += point.length();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

after inlining  this `new` will be not needed because we can extract all fields to local variables like

```java
Point point = new Point(i, i);
double x = point.x;
double y = point.y;
result += Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
```

->

```java
Point point = new Point(i, i);
double x = i;
double y = i;
result += Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
```

now it's obvious that `new Point(i, i)` is useless and JIT just remove this line.

Note that the allocation was on stack i.e. in a local variable. If it was in a field we'd not be able do that optimization because it's stored in the heap. 
That how it works.

about your code snipped: the `finalizerGuardian` will always in the field (stored in the heap) and JVM can do nothing with this allocation. Furemore if the class `Point` from the example above contains such field, i think escape analys is not able to remove the allocation because it might change the original behaviour.

Comment: I see what you mean. So, if either x or y were objects in Point instead of primitives (doubles) then the JIT could not do that optimization. Is that correct?

Comment: No, i think it's still able do that optimization. It's only about can JIT extract everything for the calulation to local variables or not? For example if we have `Double` fields instead of `double` we're still able to extract them to `Double x = i;` and remove the `new Pointer()` allocation.

Comment: @Qlvan then theoretically every object hierarchy can be flatted to local variables, couldn't they? Every object is an instance of a class that references objects which eventually reference objects that reference primitive types. Isn't that true? Yet this article is saying there are cases when the optimization can't be done. It would help if either of us or another contributor could think of a case where the opimization *can't* be done. Or explain the example in the documenation which I agree with maartinus is unreadable. My goal is to understand what this optimization really is.